# How to change the background color of two uibutton on single click action in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm new to iPhone app developing.In my app I'm  using tableview.In tableview I'm using two uibuttons one in  **white color** and another one in **graycolor**.If I click gray color button it should changed to white color and another button should changed to gray color on same time.

This is my code:

```
       -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ExampleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell=nil;
    if(cell == nil)
     {
         cell = [[ExampleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        postbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [postbtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 205, 160, 34)];
        [postbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [postbtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ POST",[AppDelegate.profileDic objectForKey:@"posts"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [postbtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:10]];
        [postbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [postbtn setTag:1001];
        [postbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:postbtn];

        likebtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [likebtn setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 205, 160, 34)];
        [likebtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [likebtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ LIKE",[AppDelegate.profileDic objectForKey:@"likes"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [likebtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:10]];
        [likebtn setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [likebtn setTag:1002];
        [likebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:likebtn];
        }
)};

    -(void)reloadAction:(id)sender
    {


        if ([sender tag] == 1001)
        {
           [postbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
           [likebtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            AppDelegate.selectedTab=1;
            [profiletableview reloadData];

        }
        if ([sender tag] == 1002)
        {
            [postbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [likebtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            AppDelegate.selectedTab=2;
            [self likewebservice];
            [profiletableview reloadData];
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to change the background color of uibutton.

Comment: where is the problem? your code is working or not?

Comment: You don't need to use tag
`if (sender == postbtn)` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're reloading the table immediately after the button is pressed by including:

```
[profiletableview reloadData];
```

in your `reloadAction:` method. By doing so, you're just resetting the colors to those initially defined in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Take out that line and it should work.

---

Edit:

And if you need to be able to reload the data in the table, you probably shouldn't initialize the UIButtons in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method (or at least, you shouldn't initialize the UIButtons repeatedly after the first load).  You may be best off initializing your UIButtons in the viewDidLoad method so they're initialized before the table loads, then, as you've already done, adding the UIButtons to the cell during `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and changing the button colors and values during `reloadAction:`.  I could be wrong, but you probably still won't absolutely need to reload the table during `reloadAction:` in this case, since you're directly changing the buttons and can also directly change the button titles in this same method; but, it's generally nice to have the option to reload your table without messing up your buttons.

Edit #2:

Additionally if that row remains static, you can reload only the necessary rows using  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation or, as KIDdAe said, do a full table reload, but only add the buttons to the cell if the cell==nil.

Comment: It would be best to keep some sort of state on which cells' buttons should be the different color. In `reloadAction:` update the state and let the color of the button be based on that state in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That way, reloading the table view doesn't mess things up.

Comment: In fact you probably don't need to create again those button each to time you reload your tableview.
Just handle this case in your `cellForRow` and you will be able to call `reloadData` on click

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with that @Lance.  Just stating the current problem with his code.

Comment: @LyndseyScott agreed. I wasn't trying to say your answer was incorrect, I was just pointing out that his whole approach is kind of flawed.

Comment: @Lance Yep, I know. And I was just letting him know that I agreed with you…that he could stand to make some more edits. :)

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott when I remove this [profiletableview reloadData]; function Button color changing works fine. But I need to reload the table view.Because I called the post web service in viewwillappear method. So I just reload the table it displayed the data from post web service. So in this case what can I do?

Comment: @KIDdAe Could you please tell me how to use the logic in cellForRow?

Comment: Start by adding `if (!postbtn)` before initializing it (same for the other button). See what happen, and start debugging :) ! Good luck.

Comment: @KIDdAe, For convenience sake I have just mentioned only the condition part FYI, the else part has some service data like and post. In the else part, we are reloading the tableview with some new data. But, the  buttons(UI) will be static in indexpath.row=0; So could you please prefer us some technique that retains the color of button and also reload the data.

Comment: If the first cell is completely static and will never change after init then move all the code block with `if (cell.indexPath.row == 0)` in the previous scope `if (cell == nil)`
This way, buttons will only be created when the first row is initialized. Don't forget to add `if (cell.indexPath.row != 0)` if cell != nil (because you don't want to update the first row ever again)

Comment: @KIDdAe and I also wrote a suggestion for you in my last edit

Comment: And to only reload specific rows use  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Comment: @LyndseyScott Yes I've seen your edit, but he will have to handle the `addSubview` in `cellForRow`, if he does not want to add the buttons twice.
Maybe you were suggesting to add them after tableview is completely loaded the first time ? But it does not sound that clean to me :)

Comment: @KIDdAe Yeah, I'm saying to handle addSubview in cellForRow: "adding the UIButtons to the cell during tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:"  Not after the tableview is fully loaded.  I'm just saying he should probably initialize the buttons before the table is loaded and then only update the rows he need to update by using  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: in order to have the cleanest code.

Comment: And I actually meant to tag @Karthik in that first comment about the edit.

Comment: @KIDdAe but I do see what you're saying about potentially taking advantage of the the cell being reusable.  I agree that could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to make a UIImage that is the color that you want the button to be. You can do that with the following code:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

After you run that you'll have a 1x1 pixel UIImage that is, in this case, blue. Then you will set that image as the background image for the button state that you're setting. The following will set the image for the normal (unchecked) state of the button:

```
[yourbutton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can set a custom color for the clicked state as well, using a different color above and then doing the following:

```
[yourbutton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

You could put the code for creating the image in a separate method so that you just pass it the color that you want it to make the image. Then you can set the background colors of many different buttons to different colors easily.

Comment: This used to be the case, but not anymore.  No need to do all of this to change the background color.  Really, I think the solution in this case is as I've written in my answer.